# Micronaut custom context in test using @Factory

Tags: java, unit-testing, micronaut, micronaut-test

I'm trying to find any analogue of spring's @ContextConfiguration annotation in micronaut framework

Is there any way to run unit test in micronaut using custom application context?
My project is a library without main class.
I have @Factory with initialization of my beans.

```
@Factory
public class TestConfig {
@Singleton
public QueryParameterParser queryParameterParser() { }
@Singleton
public ConnectionHolder connectionHolder(DataSource dataSource) {  }
@Singleton
public QueryExecutor queryExecutor(ConnectionHolder connectionHolder, QueryParameterParser parameterParser) { }
}
```

In spring I'd write these for using context in test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class FunctionTest {
@Autowired
private TransactionExecutor transactionExecutor;
```

The only way to do it in micronaut I've found is to create CustomContextBuilder:

```
@Introspected
public class CustomContextBuilder extends DefaultApplicationContextBuilder {
private TestConfig factory = new TestConfig();

    public CustomContextBuilder() {
        TestConfig.DataBase db = factory.db();
        DataSource dataSource = factory.dataSource(db);
        singletons(
                db, dataSource,
                queryParameterParser,
                connectionHolder,
                new MicronautFixturesTestExecutionListener()
        );
    }
```

and pass CustomContextBuilder to @MicronautTest annotation. It works but is too complicated to write code for instantiating every bean in CustomContextBuilder everytime.

Is there any way to pass my @Factory class to context and not to write all singletons?
I've tried package method and passed my @Factory package - but it didn't created context properly.

Comment: "Is there any way to run unit test in micronaut using custom application context?" - Yes.  One way to do that is by way of the `contextBuilder` attribute of `@MicronautTest`. https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/blob/master/test-junit5/src/main/java/io/micronaut/test/extensions/junit5/annotation/MicronautTest.java#L93